# Linear fit with Least Squares: what is going wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

I'm trying to do a Least Squares best fit for {1,2},{2,1},{3,3}. Unfortunately, my final formula continues to be wrong.

As my final formula, I'm getting $y=\frac{1}{7}+\frac{13}{14}x$ - instead of - $y=0.5x +1$.

Because something obviously goes wrong while calculating $b$, I have attached my notes for that part. I tried to make it as clear as possible.

[image: Link to image]

I really hope someone can help me out, thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You went from

$$\frac{3(2+2+9)-(6\times 6)}{3(1+4+9)-(6\times 6)}=\frac{2+2+9}{1+4+9}.$$

This is your problem. Why?

**EDIT:** We can go from 
$$\frac{3(2+2+9)}{3(1+4+9)}=\frac{2+2+9}{1+4+9},$$
but there is a reason *why* we can. The reason being is that $\frac{1/3}{1/3}=1$ and multiplying by one doesn't change anything; wit:
$$\frac{3(2+2+9)}{3(1+4+9)}=\frac{1/3}{1/3}\frac{3(2+2+9)}{3(1+4+9)}=\frac{\frac13 \cdot 3(2+2+9)}{\frac13 \cdot 3(1+3+9)}=\frac{1(2+2+9)}{1(1+3+9)}=\frac{2+2+9}{1+3+9}.$$

However can you do the same kind of thing, *get rid of the threes*, with say 
$$\frac{1+3}{2+3}?$$

Comment: I didn't write that 4 under the left division.

Comment: Doesn't matter... will be edited to three.

Comment: Oh.. I see it now. I shouldn't have assumed I could do that... Thanks!!

Comment: @MelvinLammerts Do it properly and you will get $\frac12=0.5$... for future reference be able to justify these so-called-cancellations. Even better never "cancel" --- the phrase is banned in my classroom. Numbers don't "cancel" or "move"...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply neglect your term $-(6\cdot 6)$ in the numerator and denominator.

When computing b with the formula you provided, I get:

$b = \frac{3\cdot (13) - 36}{3\cdot (14) - 36} = \frac{39-36}{42-36} = \frac{3}{6} = 0.5$

Just as you stated would be the right result.

Hope this helped,
Thomas

Comment: ...he thought he could "cancel" the $6\times 6$...